# Is there any options to make some children's of layout moveable and some not

Tags: java, android, touch

I am using  Relative Layout and many buttons in it .I want to make some buttons of layout moveable and some not during `OnTouch ACTION_MOVE`

```
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    view.animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                            .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    break;
```

I don't want my buttons outside of layout for some reason

When I move layout all buttons move because are inside of it, but I dont want all to move, with some words how to lock button?

Is there any options?

Answer (score 0):

You can check view ID to only move certain views.

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (view.getId() == R.id.viewIWantToMove) {
                view.animate()
                    .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                    .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();

            }    
            break;
```